# From equality of a list's rows to summation over different elements of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

My own code (for the following aim) which I think is not so good written is:

```
 Do[desired[k] = 0;
    Do[
       Do[
      If[list1[[i]] == list2[[j]], desired[k] += matrix[[i, j]]]

   , {i, 1, Length@list2}]
 , {j, 1, Length@list1}]
  , {k, 1, 5}]
```

Please see two below lists (8*5) (which are equal to each other):

```
list1 = {{1, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 
1, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 
0, 2, 0}};
list2 = {{1, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 
1, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 
0, 2, 0}};
```

Some elements of these matrices are equal, For instance: `{1, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 3, 0}`. For the future, I take `i` index from the first list and `j` from the second list.

I have another matrix as

```
matrix={{7, 6, 9, 9, 8, 8, 10, 10}, {6, 8, 10, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8}, {8, 9, 6, 8, 
  6, 9, 5, 8}, {5, 9, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 8}, {10, 5, 10, 8, 8, 5, 10, 
 6}, {10, 9, 5, 5, 10, 8, 8, 7}, {7, 6, 7, 10, 7, 9, 7, 8}, {6, 7, 6,
  5, 7, 8, 7, 10}}
```

It is an 8*8 matrix.

I am going to try sum over some elements of the matrix that their indices are obeyed by the equality of the rows of the two upper lists: (sum over `matrix[[i,j]]` in which `i` is from the first list and `j` from the second one).I mean

```
    (*{1,0,0,3,0}*)
     desired[1] = matrix[[1, 1]] + matrix[[1, 2]] + matrix[[2, 1]] +  matrix[[2,2]];
   (*{3,0,0,2,0} *)
    desired[2] = matrix[[3, 3]] + matrix[[3, 8]] + matrix[[8, 3]]+ matrix[[8, 8]];
   (*{3,0,0,1,0}*)
    desired[3] = matrix[[4, 4]];
   (*{2,0,0,3,0} *)
    desired[4] = matrix[[5, 5]];
   (*{3,0,0,3,0}*)
     desired[5] =matrix[[6, 6]] + matrix[[6, 7]] + matrix[[7, 6]] + matrix[[7, 7]];
```

for the last case `((*{3,0,0,2,0}*))` we do not need a new calculation because it was considered.

Is an efficient code? Also I put the `{k, 1, 5}` by hand. I saw that the `k` cannot exceed form `5`.

Comment: Thinking about this further, I'm less sure I understood what you want before answering.  Why are there two lists (`list1` and `list2`)?  Can they be different?  What if `list1` has a value which is absent from `list2`?

Comment: For more clear I just wrote twice. I wanted to show for index `i` and `j`

Comment: Ok, let me ask you about a smaller case, where `list1` and `list2` are different.  Suppose `matrix={{a,b},{c,d}}` and `list1={x,y}` while `list2={y,z}`.  What is the desired output?  Is it `desired[1] = matrix[[2,1]]`?

Comment: @jjc385, Yes, exactly. Your propose and its results is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit2**:  This answer only looks at the case where `list2` is identical to `list1`, because that was the only example given in the question.  It seems that [Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9754/coolwater)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149776/11035) handles multiple lists the way OP would like.

---

If I understand correctly, you first want to group the row indices of like elements of the first list.  You can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) :

```
Thread[list1 -> Range@Length@list1];
GroupBy[%, First -> Last]
```

> ```
> <|{1, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {1, 2}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0} -> {3, 8}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 0} -> {4}, {2, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {5}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {6, 7}|>
> ```

Then you can generate all combinations of matrix indices from each group:

```
Tuples[#, 2] & /@ %
```

> ```
> <|{1, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0} -> {{3, 3}, {3, 8}, {8, 3}, {8, 8}}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 0} -> {{4, 4}}, {2, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {{5, 5}}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> {{6, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}}|>
> ```

Finally you can perform the sum over the specified matrix elements:

```
Sum[Extract[matrix, inds], {inds, #}] & /@ %
```

> ```
> <|{1, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> 27, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0} -> 30, {3, 0, 0, 1, 0} -> 6, {2, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> 8, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0} -> 32|>
> ```

```
Values@%
```

> ```
> {27, 30, 6, 8, 32}
> ```

This agrees with your expected result:

```
 Array[ desired, 5 ]
```

> ```
> {27, 30, 6, 8, 32}
> ```

---

All together, for easier copying:

```
Thread[list1 -> Range@Length@list1];
GroupBy[%, First -> Last]
Tuples[#, 2] & /@ %
Sum[Extract[matrix, inds], {inds, #}] & /@ %
Values@%
```

---

**Edit**:  [Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9754/coolwater)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149776/11035) below taught me about [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html), which much more compactly gives exactly the same output as the first two lines of my code.  So my code can be replaced with:

```
PositionIndex[list1]
Tuples[#, 2] & /@ %
Sum[Extract[matrix, inds], {inds, #}] & /@ %
Values@%
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR ANSWER AND EXPLANATION

Comment: I think the final sort of your results is better. However the @Coolwater's answer is very professional and compacted.

Comment: How the `Tuples[#, 2] & /@` recognizes that it must applied on `{1, 2}` or `{3,8}` and not `{1, 0, 0, 3, 0}` and so on. You `Map` `Tuples` on the result of the previous procedure. but this procedure does not have just `{1, 2}` or `{3,8}`. It contains `{1, 0, 0, 3, 0}` and so on. My problem is how program know that where it must be apply!!!!!

Comment: @Irreversible [Map (`/@`) has special behavior on Associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html#495990727).  The keys (in this case, the 5-element lists from `list1`) are ignored -- they are only labels -- and the specified function (in this case, `Tuples[#, 2] & /@`) is only mapped to the values.  If you don't like having the keys, you can apply `Values@%` (which gets rid of the keys) before applying `Tuples`, rather than at the end.

Comment: Yes you are right. PositionIndex[list1][[1]]={1,2}

Comment: Map[f, <|a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 1, d -> 5|>]=<|a -> f[4], b -> f[2], c -> f[1], d -> f[5]|>

Answer (score 3):

```
Total[Extract[matrix, {##}] & @@@ MapThread[Tuples@*List,
        Lookup[{##}, Union[Keys[#], Keys[#2]], {}]], {2}] &[
                   PositionIndex[list1], PositionIndex[list2]]
```

> {27, 8, 6, 30, 32}

If you only need the sum of them replace the last `List` by {1, 2}

Comment: I am trying to understand steps of your procedures. Specially I am not familiar to some commands you used. but it seems amazing.

Comment: Even if it did take some work to understand your answer, I think you understood OP's request better than I did.  +1, especially for showing me `PositionIndex` and `Lookup`.

Comment: Also, perhaps `DeleteDuplicates@Join` would put the results in a more natural order than `Union`, though admittedly the desired order is somewhat ill-defined for unequal `list`s.